Struggling with getting Nuxt and Vite-PWA to work offline
I've been struggling for hours with what should have been a trivial thing to do with vite-pwa module for Nuxt. So I turn to you wise folk to help me out.
I'm trying to build a simple Nuxt app that will work offline and users can add it to their home screens or computers. Important bit is I need it to work offline even if user is on a plane/tunnel and presses the refresh button in browser.
Right now, I'm just getting the default no internet page in Chrome, and even worse when I try to print out contents of the $pwa object, I'm getting 'false' on all the attributes (swActivated, offlineReady…).
Here's what I've got in nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
   compatibilityDate: "2024-04-03",
   devtools: { enabled: false },
   modules: ["@vite-pwa/nuxt", "@nuxt/ui"],
   ssr: false,

   pwa: {
      registerType: "autoUpdate",
      manifest: {
         name: "Local First Nuxt",
         short_name: "LocalFirstNuxt",
         scope: "/",
         start_url: "/",
         theme_color: "#ffffff",
         background_color: "#ffffff",
         icons: [
            {
               src: "pwa-64x64.png",
               sizes: "64x64",
               type: "image/png",
            },
            {
               src: "pwa-192x192.png",
               sizes: "192x192",
               type: "image/png",
            },
            {
               src: "pwa-512x512.png",
               sizes: "512x512",
               type: "image/png",
            },
            {
               src: "maskable-icon-512x512.png",
               sizes: "512x512",
               type: "image/png",
               purpose: "maskable",
            },
         ],
      },
      workbox: {
         globPatterns: ["**/*"],
      },
      includeAssets: ["**/*"],
      client: {
         installPrompt: true,
      },
      devOptions: {
         enabled: true,
         type: "module",
      },
   },
});

And I've got the pwamanifest in App.vue
   
Any help would be greatly appreciated?

The problem is exotic and specific to relatively low-profile plugin, a way to quickly reproduce it will definitely help, because this looks like something that needs to be debugged
